# Difference between iterative and incremental software process model?

Tags: software-design

I have confusion in understanding the difference between  iterative and incremental software process model?
what is the main reason of making these two software model if they both works same?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about project management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that kind of difference to have an iterative process or an incremental process. Models use the terms to describe the process, but there are models that are both incremental and iterative.

See https://www.testingexcellence.com/iterative-incremental-development-agile/

Answer (score 2):

There is a software design principal: *Design iteratively, build incrementally.*

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_design):

> Iterative design is a design methodology based on a cyclic process of
> prototyping, testing, analyzing, and refining a product or process.
>
> ...
>
> The process should be repeated until user issues have been reduced to
> an acceptable level.

From *Righting Software by Juval Lowy*:

> While the car company may have had a team of designers designing a car
> across multiple iterations, when it is time to build the car, the
> manufacturing process does not start with a skateboard, grow that to a
> scooter, then a bicycle, then a motorcycle, and finally a car.
> Instead, a car is built incrementally. First, the workers weld a
> chassis together, then they bolt on the engine block, and then they
> add the seats, the skin, and the tires. They paint the car, add the
> dashboard, and finally install the upholstery.
>
> There are two reasons why you can build only incrementally, and not
> iteratively. First, building iteratively is horrendously wasteful and
> difficult (turning a motorcycle into a car is much more difficult than
> just building a car). Second, and much more importantly, the
> intermediate iterations do not have any business value. If the
> customer wants a car to take the kids to school, what would the
> customer do with a motorcycle and why should the customer pay for it?